# laravel - dynamic dropdown list based on previous selection

Tags: jquery, mysql, forms, laravel, dropdown

I have a dropdown list that is being populated from my database, but I am trying to make a 2nd dropdown list that is based on the first lists selection.

The 2nd dropdown lists contents have an FK pointing to the contents of the first drop down list:

```
 project table         assignment table
 id|project_name       id|project_id|labour_type
  1|abc                 1|         1|....
  2|def                 2|         1|....
  3|..                  3|         2|....
```

I am generating the first dropdown by -

Controller:

```
$projects = DB::table('project')->lists('project_name', 'id');
```

Form:

```
{!! Form::select('project', $projects) !!}
```

I am not sure how to even start a controller query for the 2nd dropdown.

I am new to laravel/php but not familiar at all with jQuery/ajax, and I know it will be what I have to use to avoid having to refresh the page to update the 2nd dropdown. Any help is appreciated.

edit: Would it make sense to have both dropdowns be queries from the assignment table, and find a different way to display the project name in the first dropdown?

Thanks.

Comment: Two possible solutions: 1) Either use ajax 2) Or use the on dropdown change event and pre-populated the data from the database.

Comment: With ajax I could filter my db queries? Sorry, I've never used ajax. If I just pull all the assignments and put them in the drop down, I could use ajax to only display the ones that join project and assignment table on the id of the project selected from the previous dropdown?

Comment: Yes, learn ajax. It's not that tough. If you have knowledge of jQuery, that wouldn't take much time.

Comment: I don't have knowledge of jquery but knowing I can use ajax on mysql is enough to get me started, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just seen your question, so I'll do my best to try and answer.

First off, you need to listen to the `change` event on your first `select` element, not sure what it is since it's not in the question but for now I'll call it `dropdown-1`, e.g. `<select id="dropdown-1"></select>`

```
$(document).on('change', '#dropdown-1', updateDropdown2);
```

What this does is call the `updateDropdown2` function whenever the value in `dropdown-1` changes.

```
var statusChanger = function () {

    var $select = $(this); // the select menu that was changed
    var projectID = $select.val();

    // send ajax request
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url:'/controller/action',
        data: {
            project_id: projectID
        },
        success: function(data) {

            var options = '';
            // you might want an empty option, so you could do
            // var options = '<option value=""></option>';

            // assuming that your data is being return as json
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                // loop through the json and create an option for each result
                options += '<option value="' + item.id + '">' + item.labour_type + '</option>';
            });

            // update dropdown 2
            $('#dropdown-2).empty().html(options);
            // the empty isn't needed since
            // .html() will replace the contents
            // but it's just to make it obvious what is happening

        }
    });
}
```

Here I am prefixing some variables with a `$` sign, this is just a convention that some people use to signify that the element contains a jQuery object, rather than just a string, integer etc.

Some things you'll need to implement:

- a route for the ajax request (e.g. replace `url:'/controller/action',` with the actual url you define in your routes file
- remember to include the jQuery library on your page
- a controller and action to handle the ajax request, example below:

  ```
  public function getLabourTypes(Request $request)
  {

      $labourTypes = LabourType::where('project_id', $request->project_id)->orderBy('labour_type', 'asc')->get();

      return $labourTypes->toJson();
  }
  ```

Please note I've not tested this at all so there may be some mistakes but it should get you most of the way to what you are trying to implement.