# Call query base on another query on laraver

Tags: laravel

these is my first time i'm using laravel, and i have problem let said i have code controller like these

```
public function maleadv()
    {
        $mountain = Product_catalog::where([
                        ['gender', '=', 'male'],
                        ['background', '=', 'Mountain'],
                    ])->get();
        
        $forest = Product_catalog::where([
                        ['gender', '=', 'male'],
                        ['background', '=', 'Forest'],
                    ])->get();
        
        $rain = Product_catalog::where([
                        ['gender', '=', 'male'],
                        ['background', '=', 'Rainy'],
                    ])->get();
        
        $sport = Product_catalog::where([
                        ['gender', '=', 'male'],
                        ['background', '=', 'Sport'],
                    ])->get();
                    
        return view('productservices::prod.list', ['mountain' => $mountain,'forest' => $forest,'rain' => $rain,'sport' => $sport]);
    }
```

And i have antoher controler like these

```
public function getinfo($id)
    {
        $info = Product_catalog::where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('productservices::prod.list', ['info' => $info]);
    }
```

On view i just try these

```
@foreach($mountain as $adv)     
    <h1>{{ $adv->label }}</h1>
@endforeach
```

And it working show data on `maleadv` , but my problem is i wanna call `getinfo` inside  `@foreach($mountain as $adv)` but base on value `$adv->id`. Can anyone help me??

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33660225/laravel-dynamic-dropdown-list-based-on-previous-selection

Comment: @PalakJadav that case using ajax. and my case i'm not using ajax...

Comment: here your requirement is not clear what you exactly want to do

Comment: @PalakJadav like i said i wanna show data from funciton call getinfo inside function of @foreach($mountain as $adv) . Is that clear??

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this, you don't need to call getinfo() function.

```
@foreach($mountain as $adv)     
    <h1>{{ $adv->label }}</h1>
    {{ App\Product_catalog::find($adv->id) }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: okay that's make sense but how do i show my data from {{ Product_catalog::find($adv->id) }}?? Edit nevermind is error, Product_catalog is not function.

Comment: have you save you file with  .balde.php  extension?